# How to output tensor flow prediction results in .csv?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am training a model using CNN.

Here is my prediction part in the model.

```
predictions = {
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logit2, axis=1),
    "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logit2, name="softmax_tensor")
}
```

Here is the code in main that do the evaluation.

```
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": images_test},
    y=test_labels,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)
eval_results = model.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
```

I have trained my models, now I have a list of test image names (in the first column of a csv file), and I want to make the predictions and output the corresponding results to the second column (with probability between 0 and 1), how to achieve this, and where to add the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Estimator` class has a [predict function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#predict) that returns the predictions as an iterable object (for an example, [scroll to the very bottom of this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators#the_complete_abalone_model_fn)).

so you could do:

```py
predictions = model.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)
for p in predictions: 
  # write p['classes'] to the csv
```

As for writing to the second column of the csv, take a look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) python module.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by the type of the predictions, and this clears it, I somethings complicate things.

Comment: Do you know how to write the prediction to file? even text file works, I keep getting errors when trying to do  f.write(str(pre['probabilities'])+"\n"), with str() or without both don't work. Thanks!!!

Comment: What error do you get when you try to write to the text file?